# Retrive All the SharePoint List Items using JSOM

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-addin

I had a requirement ,Need to get all the items of "Customers" List using JSOM and show in

tag.I had written my code ,But found no luck can any one help me how the issue in below code.

```
    <script>
SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', retrieveListItems);
function retrieveListItems()
{
var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('CalerndarExecution');

var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
camlQuery.set_viewXml("<View><Query><OrderBy><FieldRef Name='Function' Ascending='TRUE' /></OrderBy></Query></View>";);

this.collListItem = oList.getItems(camlQuery);
clientContext.load(collListItem);
clientContext.executeQueryAsync( Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded),Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed) );
}

function onQuerySucceeded(sender, args)
{
   var listItemInfo = '';
   var listItemEnumerator = collListItem.getEnumerator();
    while (listItemEnumerator.moveNext()) {
                var oListItem = listItemEnumerator.get_current();
                listItemInfo +=' <strong>Title:</strong> ' + oListItem.get_item('Function') +'<br />';
                }  $("#p").val(listItemInfo);
}


function onQueryFailed(sender, args)
{
alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() +'\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}
</script>

<p></p>
```

Comment: What's the internal name for Function field?

Answer (score 0):

Are you getting any error message?

If not try to set the `id` as `p` to the paragraph element, like below.

```
<p id="p"></p>
```

Because `$("#p")` is the jQuery selector for id.

Ensure "Function" is a column's internal name use the below code, otherwise replace "Function" with the internalname of the column.

Call the retrieveListItems method by end of the code.

Below is the formatted and working code.

```
function retrieveListItems() {
var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('CalendarExecution');
var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
camlQuery.set_viewXml("<View><Query><OrderBy><FieldRef Name='Function' Ascending='TRUE' /></OrderBy></Query></View>");
this.collListItem = oList.getItems(camlQuery);
clientContext.load(collListItem);
clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));
}

function onQuerySucceeded(sender, args) {
var listItemInfo = '';
var listItemEnumerator = collListItem.getEnumerator();
while (listItemEnumerator.moveNext()) {
    var oListItem = listItemEnumerator.get_current();
    listItemInfo += ' <strong>Title:</strong> ' + oListItem.get_item('Function') + '<br />';
}
$('#p').html(listItemInfo);
}

function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}

SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', retrieveListItems);

</script>

<p id='p'></p>
```